# Editable List in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a list which a user can not only edit individual steps, but edit the number of steps as well. How can I do this in Angularjs?

The problem I'm having is that if I use ng-model in the "ol" I don't think I can create a list of individual elements, but if I use ng-repeat in the "li" then I don't think I can add new elements to the list. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: the best manner will be using yourList.push(...) and yourList.splice(yourList.length-1, 1)... you can believe on ngRepeat, it will update the list

Comment: Do you have some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

JS:

```
$scope.range = function(min, max, step) {
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
        input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
}

$scope.list = [];

$scope.printlist = function(){
    console.log($scope.list);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" ng-click="printlist()" ng-model="len">
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="n in range(0,len-1)"><input type="text" ng-model="list[n]"></li>
</ol>
```